# Comma separate select items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with two select elements and the idea is when a client selects multiple items in select1 then they will be placed in select2. This works fine for single items but when I select multiple items they appear all in one line with no separation on the items.

I would be grateful if someone helps me with this. I have posted the jQuery I am using, but if you also need the HTML, then I shall post. Many thanks

HTML

```php
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("sample",$conn); 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM boxes where department = '{$_GET['dept']}'");
?>

    <select name="boxdest[]" id="boxdest" size="7" multiple="multiple">

<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["custref"];?>"><?php echo $row["custref"];?></option>
<?php
    $i++;
    }
?>
</select>
```

```javascript
$("#submit2").click( function() {

    //alert('button clicked');

    $box1_value=$("#boxdest").val();
    $box1_text=$("#boxdest option:selected").text();
    $("#boxdest2").append('<option value="'+$box1_value+'">'+$box1_text+'</option>');
    $("#boxdest option:selected").remove();

});
```

Comment: Yes, do post the HTML please

Comment: _"but when I select multiple items"_ How is more than one `<option>` selected at one time?

Comment: @guest271314 `<select multiple>`

Comment: `val()` returns an array for `<select multiple>` and `text()` will return the concatenated text of all the elements in selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // initial list, as fetched from the server
  var initialList = $('#boxdest > option')
    .map(function () { return this.value; }).get();

  /**
   * @param {string} source
   * @param {string} destination
   */
  function exchangeLists(source, destination) {
    // find all selected items on the source list
    var selected = $(source + ' > option:selected');

    // move them to the destination list
    $(destination).append(selected.clone());

    // remove from the source list
    selected.remove();

    // sort the destination list
    var list = $(destination + ' > option').clone().sort(function (a, b) {
      if (initialList.indexOf(a.value) < initialList.indexOf(b.value)) {
        return -1;
      }

      if (initialList.indexOf(a.value) > initialList.indexOf(b.value)) {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
    });

    // replace current destination list with the sorted one
    $(destination).empty().append(list);
  }

  $('#submit2').click(function () {
    exchangeLists('#boxdest', '#boxdest2');
  });

  $('#submit3').click(function () {
    exchangeLists('#boxdest2', '#boxdest');
  });
});
```

Comment: This is working of sorts but it is removing items on each click from #boxdest2 when i enter new items. I need to populate until user clicks the button to empty. thanks

Comment: Should the items be unique? If not, check if removing `.empty()` will help you.

Comment: But if I remove the .empty() event then the items will still be in the list

Comment: Sure, but you’ve said you “need to populate until user clicks the [another?] button”. Which is the button to empty and what should get emptied? And when should `#boxdest2` get populated? After `#submit2` click?

Comment: What I need to happen is once the user has clicked #submit2 the selected items should be removed from the list and put into the 2nd list. however, if the user clicks #submit3 then the items should be returned to the original location and the selected items removed from the 2nd list. hope that makes sense. thanks

Comment: thanks for that and sorry to be a pain. But what is happening is that if a user needs to remove an individual item from #boxdest2 then it removes all entries. could you reflect the code to allow for individual entries. thanks

Comment: many thanks. The only problem remaining is, could they be put back in the order they were in originally. at the moment, it puts removed entries from #boxdest2 at the bottom of the list in #boxdest. The list is in ASC order. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can build a comma-separate list of the option labels like this:

```
$box1_text = $("#boxdest option:selected").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(", ");
```

That extracts each `<option>` label separately (via `.map()`), and then joins them together.

The `.get()` call is necessary to convert the jQuery object that's returned from `.map()` into a plain array containing all the option labels.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure. That line of code in the OP question about `$box1_text` looks to me as if it's trying to get the option labels; that's why it's calling `.text()`.  As written, that code would do exactly what the OP says: concatenate all the labels without any spaces or commas.